# Windows 7: Merging WiFi and Ethernet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

So I'm getting really annoyed with this, tried everything I can find on the internet and have had no luck clearing this up. I have, WiFi 2.4, WiFi 5.0 and Ethernet. Windows 7 will always automatically merge the 5.0 connection and the Ethernet connection into one network location.

The 2.4 connection stays a separate network location.

How can I get the 5.0 connection to un-merge with the Ethernet connection.?

I've deleted every registry entry connected to networking and the profile files in `ProgramData` and when I reconnect it, it always does this.

This is a screenshot of the merged version:

[image: merged version]

This is a screenshot of the unmerged version:

[image: unmerged version]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your network connections screen showing them merged and unmerged?

Comment: I incorporated the information of your answer into your question. Please get used to include your improvements to your question as edits of your answer and not answers.

Comment: You need to use the contact us link to get your registered and unregistered accounts merged.