# Network bridge Guest Wifi and Ethernet LAN

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, nas

I have a modem (Fritz!Box7490) that has wifi and a Guest network as well as the main network, and can act as a NAS.

After I saw that my TV can access any file on the network, and my friend - who was on the Guest network - couldn't send Netflix to the TV, I put the TV on the Guest network and removed the Ethernet cable from the TV.

So now, if I want to cast anything to the TV, which I want more often than accessing files on the NAS and RDPing my PC, I have had to have my phone, tablet, etc set to the Guest network.

Sometimes I want to RDP to the my main PC (Windows 7 on Ethernet LAN (without wifi)) or access the NAS.
Then I need to switch my phone or tablet over to the main wifi network.
(PC Network connection is set to "work" so I can use networking features.)

If my phone/tablet has both main and Guest wifi networks passwords remembered, it seems to grab either, so it's unpredictable which I'll be on on any given day, so my phone and tablet have 'forgotten' the main network so I know I'll connect to guest - no security risk, no inability to cast to TV.

usersally I'd have my devices on the main network, so they can RDP the PC, and access files on the NAS, but then I want to be able to keep visitors on the Guest network.

There may be a way to have the TV on the main wifi network, but stop the TV from seeing anything other than the files I allow, but I don't know if I can or how.
I'd still probably want the TV on Guest wifi for visitors to cast to.
Maybe the TV can have Ethernet plugged in as well and have access to both networks.

Is it possible - and desirable - to create a network bridge on the PC so I can RDP it from a device on the Guest wifi?
If so, would that expose the main network to any users on the Guest wifi?

Or would it be possible to put my devices (phone, tablet) on the main wifi network, so they can access NAS and RDP; and then somehow be able to cast to Guest network?
Is there an easier way to switch or avoid switching between networks when I want to access the NAS or RDP the PC?

James

Possible associated questions:

[Windows 7: Merging WiFi and Ethernet](https://superuser.com/questions/1149158/windows-7-merging-wifi-and-ethernet)

[Windows network bridge not working for guests](https://superuser.com/questions/1180198/windows-network-bridge-not-working-for-guests)

Comment: I don't think you understand the concept of "Guest Network", but it's very definition as it is widely accepted, it is just for a device to connect to the Internet without any ability to access any other resource on the network. It is called client isolation and very common for guest networks. I am not familiar with Fritzbox, but I assume it is a SOHO or consumer grade router, which in general does not allow specific firewall rules to allow one network to access specific devices on another. What you are looking for is likely beyond the capability of your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....smart tv connects to home network. One network at a time.
Got a couple of bucks and a spare HDMI port?  Set up a Chromecast connected to the guest network. Then all you need to do is switch inputs on the tv. No security concern that way.